# Can't find my App in Google Android market

Tags: android, google-play

I have published an app with this AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<supports-screens
android:smallScreens="true"
android:normalScreens="true"
android:largeScreens="true"
android:anyDensity="false"
/>
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
```

and with publish options

> Copy Protection = ON (Helps prevent copying of this application from
>   the device. Increases the amount of memory on the phone required to
>   install the application.), 
> Locations = all Locations

but i found that some device can't find it in the market, including Acer liquid, Sony Ericsson x10 mini pro, and even a Samsung Galaxy S

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Screen sizes are just one factor that's taken into account when deciding whether an application should show up in Android Market.

In particular, `<uses-feature>` tags in your manifest can also cause your application to become hidden. Even if you aren't declaring any of these, certain `<uses-permission>` tags can cause features to get implicitly required.

For example, if you request the `android.permission.CAMERA` permission, the `android.hardware.camera.autofocus` feature will automatically get required unless you say otherwise. Not all devices have a hardware autofocus, and your application won't be shown on these devices.

See the documentation on `<uses-feature>` for more info: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html

Also, keep in mind that if you have copy protection (aka forward-locking) enabled, your application won't show up on certain devices. The recommended alternative is to use the Android licensing service:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/licensing-service-for-android.html

(It's also worth noting that forward-locking will be disappearing in a few months, so you definitely should look at the licensing service if you're concerned about this. See the blog post I linked to above for more information.)